# Cannot connect to running instance of IBM Access client solutions - EHLLAPI - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, automation, screen-scraping, mainframe

I am trying to automate some tasks using the IBM iAccess client solutions emulator. However, I am struggling to successfully connect.

I took the inspiration from this code: https://github.com/afandylamusu/ehllapi/blob/dev/src/EHLLAPI/Wrapper.cs  Which I ported to VB as I'm not familiar with Dot Net and do not use C#.

This is basically what my code looks like.

```
Public Class EhllapiFunc
    Public Declare Function hllapi Lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\EHLLAPI\pcshll32.DLL" (ByRef Func As Integer, ByVal DataString As StringBuilder, ByRef Length As Integer, ByRef RetC As Integer) As Integer
End Class


Public Class EhllapiWrapper
Const HA_CONNECT_PS As UInt32 = 1
    Public Function Connect(ByVal sessionID As String) As UInt32
        Dim Data As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(4)
        Data.Append(sessionID)
        Dim rc As UInt32 = 0
        Dim f As UInt32 = HA_CONNECT_PS
        Dim l As UInt32 = 4
        Return EhllapiFunc.hllapi(f, Data, l, rc)
    End Function
End Class
```

I have managed to successfully connect to the emulator just two times (return code 0), even after running the code immediately after the successful run I did not manage to connect to the session.  However, all the other times I ended with **return code 1**. I cannot really tell what made those two tries successful. Hence, I would like to ask you whether anybody does have any experience with this and could advise how to proceed to successfully connect to the emulator. Thank you!

Comment: The Connect function provides a return code of 1?   What does the documentation say that means ?

Comment: Does this apply to you ?  https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/troubleshooting-pcomm-and-hod-ehllapi-bridge-co-existence

Comment: Return code **1** means "An incorrect host presentation space ID was specified. The specified session either does not exist or is a logical printer session. This return code could also mean that the API Setting for DDE/EHLLAPI is not set on". Although, I believe I have specified correct PS ID. Anyway, I believe the link you suggested won't solve my problem as I do not have PCOMM installed.

Comment: Probably wont' fix the whole problem, but the `hllapi` function should also be declared as `Shared`

Comment: Right, it make more sense to have that function declared as Shared but as you said, it won't fix my problem.